# purpose of NotificationChannel name and description

Tags: android, push-notification

When setting up notification in Android, starting from Oreo, you need to setup also a `NotificationChannel`

In order to set it up you need to give it a `name: String` and a `description: String` which is optional.

```
val name = "test channel"
val description = "test description"
val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

val channel = NotificationChannel("ID", name, importance)
channel.description = description
```

I couldn't figure out as per the documentation why you need to enter this two values, They don't seam to show up in the UI, not even in the new Android P betas.

What are name and description used for when creating a NotificationChannel?

EDIT:

As evinced by the first two answers, I probably wasn't clear when asking. I know what `NotificationChannel` is for, It's not clear to me what the name and description attributes are for.

Answer (score 7):

> purpose of NotificationChannel

- [**`NotificationChannel`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)) enable us app developers to group our notifications into groups channels with the user having the ability to modify notification settings for the entire channel at once
- Notification Channels allow us to separate notifications into different groups/categories. Every channel would have a common functionality. It allows the user to customize their notification settings.

Feature the user can do the following things from the Apps Settings:

1. Block notifications from a particular channel.
2. Set priority/silent on different notification channels.

> purpose of NotificationChannel name

the NotificationChannel name is used for displaying NotificationChannel in the system setting

[**`setName()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setName(java.lang.CharSequence)) is used to set the name of a NotificationChannel
`setName()` Sets the user visible name of a NotificationChannel.

The recommended maximum length is 40 characters; the value may be truncated if it is too long.

> purpose of NotificationChannel  description

[**`NotificationChannel Description`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setDescription(java.lang.String))

Sets the user-visible description of a `NotificationChannel`.

specify the description that the user sees in the system settings

Answer (score 7):

The notification channel "name" shows up if the user long-presses on the notification, to (for example) turn off notifications from that particular notification channel of the app.

I don't know where the channel "description" is shown.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: The channel description is shown when you click on the specific notification channel under the notification settings of your app.

Answer (score 2):

> Purpose of NotificationChannel

- Notification Channels provide us with the ability to group the notifications that our application sends into manageable groups.
- Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. For each channel, you can set the visual and auditory behavior that is applied to all notifications in that channel. Then, users can change these settings and decide which notification channels from your app should be intrusive or visible at all.
- user can enable or disable notifications for a particular channels

Reference:-https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 1):

The user can enable or disable notifications for a channel instead of doing so across the board for your entire app.