# What is the use of notification channel name? Can we see the name in our device?

Tags: android, notifications, notification-channel

Does the notification name has any kind of affect in our app or in notification?

Comment: check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685489/purpose-of-notificationchannel-name-and-description)

Answer (score 0):

“Notification Channels” were introduced in 2017 with Android 8.0 Oreo. The idea is that apps can group different types of notifications into “channels.” Each channel can then be turned on or off by the user. You have to create the channels in android programmatically

Comment: Thx for the answer...

bt question is that what is the use of that notification channel name... mostly developers give package name or something as channel name.

Comment: check this "https://stackoverflow.com/a/65270712/16678146"